# jQuery AutoComplete clearing textbox when clicked

Tags: jquery

I having a working autocomplete but I want to keep the fragment the user typed in the textbox when they select a menu item, because I'm opening a new tab with a hyperlink.  This is for convenience, when the user goes back to the originating page, they can see and reuse the fragment they already typed.

So I added code to source event that locally stores the fragment, and then code in the select event that grabs that fragment, and puts it back in the textbox when the menu closes.

Works fine, but if I click in the textbox after this, the fragment disappears.

Below is some of the code fragment.

A second problem I can't resolve is if I select the menu item with a mouse click, the select event fires, I step through the debugger, see the fragment get populated in the textbox but when the event finishes, and I click the textbox with the fragment, the textbox empties.

To my knowledge and searching, there is no other part of my JS that firing and setting the textbox to blank when clicking in.  Was wondering if the default behavior of the change event wipes it out or something.

```
var whatstyped;

$("#q").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        whatstyped = request.term;

        // getJSON code works fine, I left it out        
         select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#q").val(whatstyped);
            $("#q").focus();
           // open bookmark in new tab
           window.open(ui.item.url,"_blank");
           return false;
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you do something like $(document).on('click', '#YourElement', function(event){ event.preventDefault(); // Your code below });

Comment: Are you sure `request.term` contains something?

Comment: request.term is fine, I actually see request.term's value get put into the textbox. then when select event is done, and I click the textbox with request.term in it, the value disappears.

Comment: @Joshua, that was slick - it worked.  In this capacity, what is preventDefault() preventing again? Thanks both of you.

Comment: How about the second problem, why selecting the menu item with a click ( still fires select ) but doesn't keep the fragment in the textbox, even though I see it in the textbox when stepping through the select event? Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked, I added it as an answer below

Comment: try event.preventDefault(); after select: function(event,ui) { event.preventDefault(); ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try event.preventDefault(). This stops the events normal action from firing. In the code below it stops the default click event from firing.

```
$(document).on('click', '#YourElement', function(event){
      event.preventDefault(); 
      // Your code below 
});
```